# Backtracking a recursive problem to solve balanced parentheses

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, parentheses

I need to understand How to backtrack from a recursive function. I know how it is done for basic functions like factorial or Fibonacci. I do not understand it for this problem.

I have tried eliminating the other conditions in the second recursive call but it generates all possible parentheses sets including unbalanced ones too.

```
public final class Example {
    public static void parentheses(int left, int right, String str) {
        if (left == 0 && right == 0) {
            System.out.print(str);
            System.out.print(", ");
        }

        if (left > 0) {
            str += "(";
            parentheses(left - 1, right, str);
        }

        if (right > 0 && right > left) {
            str += ")";
            parentheses(left, right - 1, str);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        parentheses(3, 3, "");
    }
}
```

I want the result to be all possible sets of balanced parentheses However after every recursive call I get 1 additional left parenthesis. The Expected Output is :

> ((())), (()()), (())(), ()(()), ()()(),

The output I get is :

> ((())), ((()()), ((()()(), (()(()), (()(()(),

Comment: There is difference between backtracking and recursive calls. Recursion is not backtracking.

Comment: If you're using recursion, what you call backtracking isn't backtracking. What you're thinking of is "returning early": you return once you either have "a desired result", or "a known to never yield a desired result". On a code note: don't pass in `str`, make the function _return_ `str` and then aggregate those returns as you run. Don't return anything until one is 0 and the other is 1, and then return the appropriate string, then _after_ the recursive step, assemble into the larger string that you return.

Comment: don't see what the input is...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the below.

```
 str += "(";
```

you are creating a new string object every time and passing it along in the recursive call. As a result, each recursive call has a different value for the string object and hence your expected recursion fails. Strings are immutable in Java.

**Change your code to below:**

```
        public static void parentheses(int left, int right, String str) {

        if ( right==0 && left==0) {
            System.out.print(str);
            System.out.print(", ");

        }
        if (left > 0) {
            parentheses(left-1, right, str +"(" ); // New object will be created but its value will be dereferenced from the old one and attached to the new one.
            // As a result all our manipulation of string we did will be saved.
        }
        if ( right >0 && right > left) {
            parentheses(left, right - 1, str +")" );
        }
    }
```

**Input:**

```
parentheses(3,3,""); // Function call
```

**Output:**

```
((())), (()()), (())(), ()(()), ()()(),
```